# 2-way Client-Server

Tags: perl, sockets, client-server

Can anyone direct me to a 2-way Client-Server Script developed in IO::Socket::INET that **sends and receives text messages?**
I need to study the flow and working of it. TY.

Comment: I have been trying to write one, but I have bot been able to develop one. I have also not been able to find an appropriate code. So if you could show me one..

Comment: haven't you gone through this one... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15844918/2-way-communication-between-server-client-scripts

Comment: This can help, but not 2-way I guess.. http://www.conceptsolutionsbc.com/perl-articles-mainmenu-41/25-modules-and-packages/54-writing-client-server-applications-using-iosocket

Comment: that ques was asked by me only. lol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the simplest solution for the above mentioned problem:

**SERVER SCRIPT**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use IO::Socket::INET;

my $socket;
my  $clientsocket;
my $serverdata;
my $clientdata;

$socket = new IO::Socket::INET (
    LocalHost => '127.0.0.1',
    LocalPort => '0155',
    Proto => 'tcp',
    Listen => 1,
    Reuse => 1
) or die "Oops: $! \n";
print "Waiting for the Client.\n";


$clientsocket = $socket->accept();

print   "Connected from : ", $clientsocket->peerhost();     # Display messages
print   ", Port : ", $clientsocket->peerport(), "\n";

# Write some data to the client  
$serverdata = "This is the Server speaking :)\n";
print $clientsocket "$serverdata \n";

# read the data from the client
$clientdata = <$clientsocket>;
print "Message received from Client : $clientdata\n";

$socket->close();
```

**CLIENT SCRIPT:**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use IO::Socket::INET;

my $socket;
my $serverdata;
my $clientdata;

$socket = new IO::Socket::INET (
  PeerHost => '127.0.0.1',
  PeerPort => '0155',
  Proto => 'tcp',
) or die "$!\n";

print "Connected to the Server.\n";

# read the message sent by server.
$serverdata = <$socket>;
print "Message from Server : $serverdata \n";

# Send some message to server.
$clientdata = "This is the Client speaking :)";
print $socket "$clientdata \n";

$socket->close();
```

Comment: this is a sweet code! :) TY

Answer (score 2):

It's just like any other file handle.

```
while (<$socket>) {    # Receiving
   print $socket $_;   # Sending
}
```

Comment: I can send text from the client to the server but I am unable to send it across to the server (the acknowledgment).
Is there a need of any wait for response or any such thing in the prog?

Comment: Of course you have to wait for a response. If your client exits without getting the response, it's not going to get it. You need to wait just like I showed the server doing.